# Using a given RSA fingerprint in SFTP Connection Golang

Tags: go, ssh, sftp

I am in the process of trying to write an sftp server in Go and my language knowledge is very limited and I can't seem to find this one answer. I have the RSA fingerprint already given to me to connect to the host but I can't seem to find anyone who gives the fingerprint. Everyone seems to generate the .pem files etc. But I just want to give it the key.

I attemped to just add the fingerprint to the ssh.NewPublicKey() but that didn't seem to work. Does anyone have any references or suggestions? Here's the code below.

I can do this pretty easily in powershell but I'm trying to get away from it and switch over to Golang.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/pkg/sftp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    addr := "remote.server:00"
    hostKey := ssh.NewPublicKey("ssh-rsa 2048 00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee")
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "username",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("password"),
        },

        HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    }
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
    }
    client, err := sftp.NewClient(conn)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create client: " + err.Error())
    }
    // Close connection
    defer client.Close()
    cwd, err := client.Getwd()
    println("Current working directory:", cwd)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, you mention writing a server, but this is code is making a client connection. A fingerprint is just a hash of a key, it's not used for authentication. In order to authenticate with a key, you need that key. This can't compile anyway, since `ssh.NewPublicKey` returns an error value, which would show that you don't have a valid public key.

Comment: My apologies. I'm using the client to connect to a remote SFTP server. The provider has given us the fingerprint. And using Powershell with WinSCP all that was needed was to provide the fingerprint before. So I'm trying to find out if it's possible to add the fingerprint to the client call.

Comment: The fingerprint has nothing to do with authentication, and it's not required. If you want to verify the fingerprint (though this is an old format), just hash the key data in a matching format and compare the string.

Comment: @JimB Okay, and what is the best way to get the fingerprint from the connection? I can't seem to find anything on that. I know it's an old format but it's a step we take in authenticating our connection.

Comment: A fingerprint is just a hash of the key. Have you looked at the "Fingerprint" functions in the ssh package? [FingerprintLegacyMD5](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#FingerprintLegacyMD5)
 and [FingerprintSHA256](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#FingerprintSHA256)